# Get a list of installed python packages with AWS EMR Notebooks

Tags: amazon-emr

I'm using AWS EMR Notebooks with the PySpark kernel.

Within my notebook, I'd like to use Python to analyze a list of the Python packages installed.

The following displays the list of packages, but the `packages` variable appears to be `None`

```
packages = sc.list_packages()
type(packages)  # <class 'NoneType'>
```

How can I get a list of packages into a Python variable for further analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have the virtualenv spark config is set to `"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true"` Here is the example config:

```html
%%configure -f
{ "conf":{
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type":"native",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path":"/usr/bin/virtualenv"
         }
}
```

Checkout the following documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/